# Calculate the height of a UITextView's text with sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode doesn't seem to return correct results

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, uitextview

I'm trying to calculate the height of the text constrained by a UITextView but it doesn't seem to return correct results.

Here is my code :

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)aTextView {
    CGSize textSize = [aTextView.text sizeWithFont:aTextView.font constrainedToSize:aTextView.frame.size lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    counter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", textSize.height];
}
```

You can download [the sample project and a short screencast that illustrates the problem (418 KB)](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40466/tmp/bugs/TestTextView/code_and_screencast.zip).

In summary, the problem is that when I type a long word at the end of a line, the word is moved to the next line, but the height of the string isn't correctly adjusted when it happens.

Any help appreciated.

Best,
Thomas.

P.S. : It happens with the iPhone SDK 3.1.3

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that the UITextField has a slight margin around the area it actually draws and wraps the text. As far as I know there is no programatic way to get this size, but just subtracting 6 or so from the size should make it behave appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
My guess is indeed that the UITextView has some kind of padding.
I would have liked to have a clean way to determine its size.

In my example, substracting 11 to the textView width and height does the trick.

Comment: Like this :
 :
    - (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)aTextView {
         CGSize textViewSize = aTextView.frame.size;
         textViewSize.width-= kTextViewPadding;
         textViewSize.height-= kTextViewPadding;
         CGSize textSize = [aTextView.text sizeWithFont:aTextView.font constrainedToSize:textViewSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
         counter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", textSize.height];
    }

Comment: I'd say file a radar, and for the time being use a hardcoded value.

Glad you figured it out

Comment: Joshua, do you know if UILabel has a similar padding?