# Get size UITextView from UITableViewCell?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have my custom UITableViewCell with UITextView in it. 
After UITableView loads I need to adjust the size of the UITableViewCell with size of the text in a UITextView.
So I am trying to it like this:

```
  - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
  {
      CGFloat resHeigth;

      resHeigth = MyCell.textView.contentSize.height;
      resHeigth += TOP_BOTTOM_MARGINS * 2;

      return resHeigth;
  }
```

But heightForRowAtIndexPath called before cellForRowAtIndexPath, where I actually set the text.

```
  MyViewCell *cell = (MyViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];

    if (cell == nil) {

        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCellView" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = MyCell;
    }

    cell.textView.text  = @"Text for test\nTest";

    CGRect frame = cell.textView.frame;
    frame.size.height = cell.textView.contentSize.height;
    cell.textView.frame = frame;
```

So, Is it possible to change the height of the UITableViewCell?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the text available as NSString, then you can use NSString's instance method [sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) to measure the size that this string will take. Using that you can set the cell height in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Update:
In the constrainedToSize parameter you can set the height to a very high value (maybe int max, or screen height), so it returns full height that this string takes.

Comment: This method does't work correct for UITextView. It is only works for UILabel

Comment: I don't think there is a difference between UITextView and UILabel apart from former having a scroll container. The sizeWithFont method is generic and you should use the `sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:` method with a definite width.

Comment: Please look at that link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330939/sizewithfont-doesnt-give-
correct-height-for-uitextview-if-there-is-a-long-string
I've tried but it is not working

Comment: oops sorry I forgot that it works with **Single Line** only. Will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the methods from [NSString UIKit Additions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) to compute the size of the text.

```
CGSize sz = [yourText sizeWithFont:cellTextFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(textFieldWidth,CGFLOAT_MAX);
```

Will return the size of the text when constrainted to a fixed size and uncontrainted vertically (CGFLOAT_MAX is the maximum value for floats)

Comment: This method does't work correct for UITextView. It is only works for UILabel. But I need UITableView

Comment: It works exactly the same. As soon as you use the right method designed for multiline text (and not single line, see the documentation). UITextView renders the text the same way as UILabel, except that it is editable and is embed in a scrollview.

Comment: I've just trying and it is not work correct. Here is another post about the problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141399/calculate-the-height-of-a-uitextviews-text-with-sizewithfontconstrainedtosizel
If it possible, please create the sample project

Comment: No need to create a project, I do that all the time in my own projects. And the question you gave the link to… has the answer to your question too.

Comment: So, As I understand I should add magic number to heightForRowAtIndexPath, in my case 16. But I think it is not good. Because for empty UITextView I am getting wrong value :(